# How did Tatsumaki get her powers?

Tags: one-punch-man

I came across **[*this*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/what-is-the-source-of-superpowers-in-the-one-punch-man-universe)** question and started wondering something: how did Tatsumaki get her powers in *One Punch Man*?

Some people get their powers naturally, as Saitama did:

> Although he tells everyone he got his incredible power through mere physical training, no one believes him at all. According to Saitama, after a year and a half of 100 daily push-ups, sit-ups, and squats, plus 10 km daily running, he had achieved some level of superhuman strength. [<sup>(source)</sup>](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Saitama#:%7E:text=Although%20he%20tells%20everyone%20he,some%20level%20of%20superhuman%20strength.)

And some achieve their powers through scientific body modifications, as seen with Genos:

> One day when Genos was 15, a crazy cyborg destroyed Genos' town, killed his family, and left Genos alive and severely wounded. Professor Kuseno, a doctor of justice, found Genos and modified him into a cyborg at Genos' request. [<sup>(source)</sup>](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31008/is-genos-really-a-cyborg#:%7E:text=One%20day%20when%20Genos%20was,a%20cyborg%20at%20Genos%27%20request.)

I speculated that Tatsumaki received her powers biologically, but where I currently am in the anime (I don't follow the manga), this has not been proven, and would lead to the question as to where whoever she inherited her powers got them from (which would cause a infinite loop).

So, how did Tatsumaki get her powers? Is it ever **canonically** explained?

Comment: I could very well be mistaken, but I think Tatsumaki and her sister Fubuki are born espers? Will have to search and see whether this is explicitly mentioned anywhere…

Comment: @Bahudari I think it is shown in the lastest chapters of the manga that Tatsumaki had her powers from a young age and the bureau wanted to recruit her ASAP.